# if Statements calling on random array

Tags: arrays, swift, if-statement

This is the code i have made so far. I have two words, red and black. when the red button is pressed i want an if statement that tells the user if they are wrong or right. The code picks randomly either red or black but i can't seem to figure how to match the if statement with word that is randomly picked.

```
@IBAction func red(sender: AnyObject) {

    let array = ["Red", "Black"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    print(array[randomIndex])


    if array == Int("Red") {

        colorLabel.text = "You're right"


    } else {

        colorLabel.text = "Wrong! It was a Black"
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with your code...

You don't want to pass a string into an `Int` initializer, or you'll get `nil`:

```
 Int("Red") // don't do this
```

Next, you're matching on your entire array anyway which won't work either:

```
if array == Int("Red") // will never == true
```

You want to match based on whats in your print statement:

```
var word = array[randomIndex] // set up a new variable
```

### Solution

You're going to want to try something more like this:

```
@IBAction func red(sender: AnyObject) {
    let array = ["Red", "Black"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    var word = array[randomIndex]

    if word == "Red" {
        colorLabel.text = "You're right"
    } else {  
       colorLabel.text = "Wrong! It was a Black"
    }
}
```